# Changing Underscores navigation button to a div

Tags: javascript, wordpress, underscores-wp

I am using _s for theme development, and I want to change the button tag to a div tag so that the dropdown button is a div instead. I changed to tag to div and modified navigation.js to div as well where it calls for element by tag name:

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
        <div class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false">Menu</div>
        <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
                'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
            ) );
        ?>
    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
```

and:

```
( function() {
var container, button, menu, links, i, len;

container = document.getElementById( 'site-navigation' );
if ( ! container ) {
    return;
}

button = container.getElementsByTagName( 'div' )[0];
if ( 'undefined' === typeof button ) {
    return;
}

menu = container.getElementsByTagName( 'ul' )[0];
```

I haven't changed any classes to avoid confusion for myself but can't seem to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`button = container.querySelectorAll('menu-toggle')[0];`